# Fullcalendar remove buttons borders/shadow

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I try removing the Fullcalendar Buttons borders.

```
.fc-button { border: 0px !important; }
```

But when I click on it a new border appear :
[image: fullcalendar text button]

And didn't found which element display this border.

Note : *On click the DOM not seems to change*
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that it comes from the `box-shadow` property that is added to the `button` thanks to the `:focus` pseudo-class.

You can try adding this rule :

```
.fc-button {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```